# How to set Kernel print level in compilation

Tags: linux, kernel

I would like to know how to set Kernel print level in compilation.

Meaning not by echo a value to /proc/sys/kernel/printk.

It should be ratter easy, I just couldn't find how...

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 2):

To set the default kernel printk level you need not to compile to the kernel once again.

The level is set based on the kernel command line argument `loglevel`

From the kernel documentation:

```
loglevel=   All Kernel Messages with a loglevel smaller than the
        console loglevel will be printed to the console. It can
        also be changed with klogd or other programs. The
        loglevels are defined as follows:

        0 (KERN_EMERG)      system is unusable
        1 (KERN_ALERT)      action must be taken immediately
        2 (KERN_CRIT)       critical conditions
        3 (KERN_ERR)        error conditions
        4 (KERN_WARNING)    warning conditions
        5 (KERN_NOTICE)     normal but significant condition
        6 (KERN_INFO)       informational
        7 (KERN_DEBUG)      debug-level messages
```

Refer [this](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt) for more details